# How can implement make_one_shot_iterator() function of tensorflow 1.0 in tensorflow 2.0 version?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In the sample one of [this](https://medium.com/@nimatajbakhsh/building-multi-threaded-custom-data-pipelines-for-tensorflow-f76e9b1a32f5) tutorial, it use  tensorflow 1.0. I want to implement that code in the tensorflow 2.0.

there is two part of code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from time import sleep
from time import time

# data generator
def py_gen(gen_name):
    gen_name = gen_name.decode('utf-8')
    for num in range(20):
        sleep(0.3)
        yield '{} yields {}'.format(gen_name, num)


# model operation
def model(data):
    sleep(0.1)
```

and

```py
Dataset = tf.data.Dataset
name = 'Gen_0'
ds = Dataset.from_generator(py_gen,
                            output_types=(tf.string),
                            args=(name,))
data_tf = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

and the run is:

```py
def run_session(data_tf):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        while True:
            try:
                t1 = time()
                data_py = sess.run(data_tf)
                t2 = time()
                t = t2 - t1
                model(data_tf)
                msg = 'elapsed time: {:.3f}, {}'.format(t, data_py.decode('utf-8'))
                print(msg)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('data generator(s) are exhausted')
                break
```

the `make_one_shot_iterator()` function did not implemented in tensorflow 2.0, but there is `tensorflow.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator` that can use this function.

But I want to implement this only with tf 2.0 and not use `tensorflow.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator`.

bow can I do this?

Comment: if you think my answer was helpful, kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to iteration on a dataset, you can just do

```
iterator = iter(ds)
```

I have modified your code to do that. FYI, I just removed that "decode" because I did not understand what that was supposed to do

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from time import sleep
from time import time

# data generator
def py_gen(gen_name):
    gen_name = gen_name.decode('utf-8')
    for num in range(20):
        sleep(0.3)
        yield '{} yields {}'.format(gen_name, num)


# model operation
def model(data):
    sleep(0.1)


def run_session(d):
        while True:
            try:
                t1 = time()
                data_py = d.get_next()
                t2 = time()
                t = t2 - t1
                model(ds)
                msg = 'elapsed time: {:.3f}'.format(t)
                print(msg)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('data generator(s) are exhausted')
                break                            

Dataset = tf.data.Dataset
name = 'Gen_0'
ds = Dataset.from_generator(py_gen,
                            output_types=(tf.string),
                            args=(name,))

it = iter(ds)
run_session(it)
```